# Access ADFS endpoint from Host

Tags: virtualbox, adfs, windows-server-2016, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

I'm having trouble with the following setup.

My host machine have a ubuntu SO and my I've installed a Windows Server 2016 in a virtual box.

I configured an AD FS server in the guest machine, everything is fine. What I need to do is to access an endpoint, for example: https://example.com/adfs/ls from the host.

When I try to do that it gives an error. My question is how can I make the ADFS endpoints accessible from host?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid endpoint.

Try:

https://example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Comment: It gives the same error. When I type Get-AdfsEndpoint, all my endpoint starts with https://win-nfhnmqdo5pj.cleiton.com/, where win-nfhnmqdo5pj is the name of my domain. There is some way to expose this endpoints?

Comment: What happens when you use the federation service name configured in ADFS?

Comment: My federation service has WIN-NFHNMQDO5PJ.cleiton.com as its name too.

Comment: This endpoint is open by default. This sounds like a networking / DNS error rather than ADFS specific.

Comment: I'm not an specialist in IIS or Windows, can you give me some directions?

Comment: Sorry neither am I . Use Fiddler or Wireshark to try and see what's happening.